# Facebook Like Button Error: App ID does not match Domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, app-id

I am trying to set up an app and like button on pages within my site. I thought I was all set but am getting the following error:

> The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of....

I'm lost on how to fix this.

Comment: Also, what do I need to select under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran in to this problem as well.  Cost me quite a bit of time!  It turns out that when you set your app domain, you also need to select an option from the list further down the page, with the header "Select how your app integrates with Facebook."  Most likely you can just select the first option, and enter your domain.

If you don't do this it won't actually save your domain.

Comment: Thanks. Issue solved. As soon as I selected it and added the domain it was all set. Now I am working on JS errors in IE but everything is working in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is simply not allowed in your Application settings. (Basic Info -> App Domain) And allow your domain

Comment: I keep trying to add it in the app domain field. I type it in, hit enter and it is there with a box around it. Then I save changes, go back to the settings page and it is no longer there.